# « elle ne passe pas par 4 chemins»?

Tags: expressions

En lisant [cet article](http://fr.aleteia.org/2016/11/01/les-6-phrases-a-eviter-pour-ne-pas-se-decredibiliser-au-premier-contact/?utm_campaign=NL_fr&utm_source=daily_newsletter&utm_medium=mail&utm_content=NL_fr), au quatrième point de discussion, l'auteur a écrit «elle veut vos contacts et elle ne passe pas par 4 chemins.»

Quel est le sens de cette expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comme écrit au début du paragraphe :

> La discussion ne fait que commencer et la personne entre dans le vif du sujet directement

Cette expression signifie aller directement au but, sans prendre de chemins détournés.

Comment: merci beaucoup Toto ;)

Comment: "Elle ne tourne pas autour du pot" est une expression similaire.

Answer (score 2):

La réponse de @Toto est pour moi la référence. Ce qui suit est une mise en contexte complémentaire, issue de mes recherches sur l'expression.

L'idée de "quatre chemins" fait penser au croisement de deux routes, et donc quatre chemins possibles, potentiellement liés aux directions des quatre points cardinaux.

Dans une acception positive (sans négation), "**quatre chemins**" peut donc signifier **partout** :

> Où est-il mon maître? Il vous cherche par les quatre chemins

Dans 
une acception positive (avec négation), cela évoque le problème de choix nécessaire, comme dans le proverbe  :

> Le chien a quatre pattes, mais il n’est pas capable de prendre
>   quatre chemins
>   et le besoin de faire des choix :

Je suis un peu surpris par la tournure "passer par quatre chemins", j'ai l'impression qu'"aller  par quatre chemins" (*elle n'y va pas par quatre chemins*) est la plus idiomatique. C'est ici le contraire de **tergiverser**, littéralement "tourner le dos".

Answer (score 0):

L'expression *ne pas y aller par quatre chemins* (plutôt que *passer*) signifie aller directement au sujet, à la question.

Autres expressions proches:

- *tourner autour du pot*
- *couper les cheveux en quatre*